# O que é e como funciona um Enterprise Application Bus(ESB)?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, soa, eai, esb

Algumas empresas que trabalham com containers `Java EE` dizem usar Barramentos de Aplicação, nunca trabalhei com tal recurso e gostaria de saber duas coisas sobre eles:

- o que é?
- como funcionam?

Comment: Delfino, qual é a relação direta entre *trabalhar com containers JEE* e *usam ESB*? Uma das premissas de um *service bus* é exatamente ser agnóstico em termos de tecnologia, então talvez seja legal você editar as tags da pergunta, considerando usar tags como [tag:arquitetura-de-software] ou até mesmo [tag:soa] e [tag:web-service].

Comment: Bruno como não conheço a tecnologia, apenas listei tags que representam o que tenho encontrado, eu posso editar a pergunta, mas talvez o ideal seja vc mesmo faze-lo, é uma prática saudável aqui, eu não me importo e considero um aprendizado.

Comment: Tranquilo, vou elaborar uma resposta para você assim que sobrar um tempo e já vejo esta edição :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como introdução, primeiro é necessário salientar que *ESB*s são agnósticos em termos de tecnologia, sendo esta uma premissa e inclusive fator que faz com que grandes empresas com um parque heterogêneo de aplicações adontam barramentos de serviços.

Outra coisa que você citou na pergunta é *barramento de aplicação*, eu particularmente nunca havia ouvido este termo, inclusive busquei e não encontrei nada relacionado. O padrão é mesmo o barramento de serviços, serviços estes contidos em uma aplicação

### O que é?

De forma resumida a explicação da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus) é bastante boa, ou seja, barramento de serviço é um modelo de arquitetura de software para projeto e implementação de comunicação mútua entre aplicações em um ambiente heterogêneo em que se busca uma arquitetura orientada a serviços.

Um ponto interessante que devemos salientar é que barramentos por si só não entregam arquiteturas orientadas a serviços, mas em muitos casos são essenciais para compor tal arquitetura.

Diria que os barramentos são os caras que não sabem o significado semântico das mensagens trocadas, mas que conhecem muito melhor que qualquer outra aplicação a sintaxe dos mais variados tipos de troca de informações, então eles se preocupam em ser a abstração para a troca correta de mensagens, sem se preocupar quase sempre com regras específicas do negócio.

### Como funciona?

Em um ambiente corporativo é comum termos muitas aplicações construídas nas mais diversas plataformas, cada uma possuindo (ou não) tipos de trocas de dados diferentes. Exemplos comuns são trocas de arquivos em *file system* ou `FTP`, construção de *views* em bases de dados, mensagem em algum serviço qualquer de mensageria, *web services* SOAP, *end points* REST e muitos outros padrões e formas de se disponibilizar informações para integração.

Agora imagine você ter que fazer a integração ponto a ponto de cada uma dessas aplicações? Se tivermos 10 aplicações, o que é pouco num ambiente corporativo, e cada uma delas ter seu próprio padrão de integração teríamos que implementar na unha 100 integrações!!!

É neste ponto que os *midlewares* de barramento de serviços entram, ou seja, visam abstrair e centralizar a heterogeneidade encontradas nestes ambientes corporativos, fornecendo integração com baixo acoplamento e orientado mais a configurações do que a codificação.

Barramentos possuem no mínimos estas 4 características, que podem ser [divididas em muitas outras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus#Characteristics):

- Criação e hospedagem de serviços: expõe serviços para integração entre as aplicações de forma centralizada
- Mediação de serviços: adaptadores de protocolos, mapeamento de serviços
- Roteamento de mensagens: entregam as mensagens no local correto com baixo acoplamento
- Manipulação de dados: transformam os dados de forma a entregá-los no padrão esperado por cada aplicação que consuma serviços do barramento

Cenários bem comuns em que são adotados, incluindo também os já citados, são estes:

- transformação de dados entre sistemas
- integração entre padrões e sistemas heterogêneos
- troca de arquivos entre sistemas
- troca de mensagens entre filas/tópicos/etc.
- orquestração de um processo entre diversões sistemas: cenário em que um sistema deveria integrar com *N* aplicações, mas que agora consome um único serviço do barramento
- processamento de dados e mensagens de acordo com regras de negócio
- expor sistemas legados por meio de padrões mais atuais, como serviços web
- exposição de APIs por meio de *proxy* de serviços heterogêneos já disponíveis
- etc.

Alguns exemplos de *ESB*s são estes:

- [Apache Synapse Enterprise Service Bus](http://synapse.apache.org/)
- [Mule ESB](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-open-source-esb)
- [Red Hat JBoss Fuse](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse/overview/)
- [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/)
- [Lista de ESBs na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_service_bus#Existing_ESB_products)

Este foi um resumo do que é e o que pode fazer um barramento, na documentação dos *providers* listados acima é possível ver muitas outras características e benefícios que uma corporação pode obter quando adota um barramento de serviços.

Comment: Sobre o termo Barramento de Aplicação, posso realmente ter me confundido, porém o contexto é um ambiente onde se tem diversos fornecedores de aplicação, com por exemplo instituições financeiras e há a necessidade de haver comunicação entre tais aplicações e algumas em especial que coordenam o fornecimento e manutenção de certos dados. Como nunca trabalhei com este tipo de tecnologia com certeza posso estar usando o termo errado, também pesquisei e não achei, porém o conceito é exatamente o que oferece o ESB.

Obrigado pela resposta, votei na mesma porque até o momento é a que responde.

Comment: @Delfino ok, caso tenha um cenário de aplicação fica mais simples desenhar uma arquitetura em que a solução se aplica, daí posso atualizar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, vou te dar uma resposta clara, melhor que copiar e colar aqui como o amigo fez ai.

Vamos lá, imagina que você tem uma aplicação que consome um serviço de outra. 
até ai tudo bem certo ?

Agora imagina que você tem uma aplicação que consome o serviço de outra, e essa outra consome o serviço de outra aplicação para dar sua resposta. 
Ta ficando complexo a coisa né ? 
Vai ser preciso dezenas de interfaces para você fazer isso, imagina agora se você tem centenas de middlewares rodando fazendo essa coisa de louco ai ? pra da manutenção vc vai ficar doido jovem

é ai que o barramento (ESB) entra, a ideia é que ele consuma todos os serviços e faça o roteamento e orquestração do mesmo, ele é capaz de pegar todos os wsdls ali preencher eles com mais conteúdo em tempo de execução (isso se chama orquestração), fora que ele vai te dar tradução de msgs e outras coisas, tudo com apenas uma interface (abstração de camadas).

Comment: Tipo um Facade de arquitetura de componentes..?

Comment: mais ou menos isso cara, a ideia é essa. E lembre-se, qualidade sempre.